# Calling a http post in an MVC action method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, dotnet-httpclient

I am calling a POST in an action method using `HttpClient`, but I am not sure if it is being done correctly.  I dont' need it to be async.  Basically, if a user is created on my system successfully, I create them in another system.  Here is the code I am calling:

```
 using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            var postData = new FormCollection();
            postData["api_token"] = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ApiToken"];
            postData["api_action"] = "Save";
            postData["customer_email"] = userName;
            postData["customer_password"] = password;
            var result = client.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}/api", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"]), content).Result;

            var xmlResponse = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

}
```

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: @ToddMenier - Am I calling it right?

Answer (score 1):

The following two lines:

```
var result = client.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}/api", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"]), content).Result;

var xmlResponse = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
```

should be refactored to the following:

```
var result = await client.PostAsync(string.Format("{0}/api", ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Url"]), content);

var xmlResponse = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

You have to use the `await`, because otherwise you block your thread calling the `Result` at the end of the asynchronous methods. Furthermore, you shoulnd't forget that corresponding action should return a `Task<ActionResult>`.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> ActionName()
```

Comment: Hi,  When I do this, I don't get the xml string back in xmlResponse, it returns an HttpResponseMessage which is what I don't want, I want the xml, so I can just start parsing it.